# Small commits in one branch as one commit to another

Tags: git

I have a question about refurbishing workflow.

Suppose I have two branches, *master* and *devel*.
Suppose also, that *master is clean*, for scope of the question, lets imagine it has only initial commit "Initial commit".

*devel*, however, is quite messy and has a lot of small commits.

I want those small changes in *devel* branch to be added to *master* branch as one single commit, lets say "Single commit"

In the end master must have all the changes made in devel and the history must be two commits long ("Initial commit" and "Single commit", to be precise)

Comment: Is your question if that's a good idea? Or if it's possible? Or why you get an error when you try to do that? Or why you didn't get the expected outcome when you tried to do that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried
git checkout devel
git rebase -i master

it says "invalid line1: Single commit", when I :wq

I either do something wrong, or dont know how to use -i.

or approach this from wrong side. Its more of theoretical question, so no difference if that is good idea or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ought to create a third branch, with multiple commits from the devel branch. Then, you merge the third branch into the master branch, and there you have it: two commits into the master branch.
Here is the example

1. Master branch
2. Devel branch
3. Temp branch

```
git checkout devel

git checkout -b temp

git commit 'Single Commit'

git push

git checkout master

git merge temp
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel.. in a fact.. it worked. I was looking around rebase and squash.. but hey, its a way to. Great many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a squah merge.

Your initial git graph would look similar like:

```
* ca97d57 (HEAD -> dev) dev_commit4
* 7c45353 dev_commit3
* 2f2f9f0 dev_commit2
* 721f8bc (master) Initial commit
```

So you would need just three git commands:

```
# check out master branch
git checkout master

# squash merge dev branch
git merge --squash dev

# commit squashed commits as single commit to master
git commit -m "Single commit"
```

The final git graph would contain two commits in master branch:

```
* 1c003b2 (HEAD -> master) Single commit
| * ca97d57 (dev) dev_commit4
| * 7c45353 dev_commit3
| * 2f2f9f0 dev_commit2
|/
* 721f8bc Initial commit
```